# после запуска, код не высвечивает никаких ошибок, но после того, как отправляю /start боту, то появляется куча ошибок

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
import telebot

from telebot import types
TOKEN =

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Русский язык', callback_data="russian")
    item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Профильная математика')

    markup.add(item1, item2)
    
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, {0.first_name}!'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup = markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == "russian":
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        rele1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Выберите номер", callback_data="1")

        keyboard.add(rele1)
        bot.edited_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message_id, text="replaced text", reply_markup=keyboard)

bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)